# Parameterization of an ellipse for stoke's theorem

Tags: calculus, polar-coordinates, parametrization, stokes-theorem

I have a question which requires the use of stokes theorem, which I have reduced successfully to an integral and a domain.

From this, I have the domain: $5y^2+4yx+2x^2\leq a^2$
over which I need to integrate.

This is an ellipse, and resultingly it can be parameterized, but this is where I am stuck. I don't know how to parameterize this curve in a form that I can integrate over the domain.

I understand that this can be put into polar coordinates, but the furthest that I can get is:

$5r^2sin^2(\theta) +4r^2sin(\theta)cos(\theta) +2r^2cos^2(\theta)\leq a^2 $

But then I don't really know where to go from here.

Comment: I think you may have made a mistake earlier on.  Stoke's theorem relates the surface integral over a vector field to the line integral over the boundary of the vector field.  You have described a surface not a curve.  Maybe you can go back a couple of steps and explain how you got here.

Comment: Absolutely, maybe I didn't make this clear, but I started with the line integral of a boundary curve, and using stoke's theorem I was able to reduce it to a surface integral. This surface integral acts over the domain of this elipse, which is the intersection of a sphere and a plane.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to solve your inequality for $r$:
\begin{align*}
a^2 &\geq 2 r^2 \cos^2(\theta) + 5 r^2 \sin^2(\theta) + 4 r^2 \sin(\theta) \cos(\theta)\\
&= r^2(2  \cos^2(\theta) + 5 \sin^2(\theta) + 4 \sin(\theta) \cos(\theta))\\
&= r^2(2  + 3 \sin^2(\theta) + 4 \sin(\theta) \cos(\theta)) \, .
\end{align*}
Then
$$
r^2 \leq \frac{a^2}{2  + 3 \sin^2(\theta) + 4 \sin(\theta) \cos(\theta)}
$$
(Note that the denominator is always $\geq 0$, so the inequality is preserved.)  Thus your bounds of integration should be
\begin{align*}
&0 \leq \theta \leq 2 \pi\\
&0 \leq r \leq \frac{a}{\sqrt{2  + 3 \sin^2(\theta) + 4 \sin(\theta) \cos(\theta)}} \, .
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you, I can't believe that I didn't see that.